# Trigger only clicked event in nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following setup to display rating stars:

```js
$( document ).on( 'click touch', '.rate', function() {
   alert( $(this).data('rate') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <span class="rate" data-rate="1">1
        <span class="rate" data-rate="2">2
             <span class="rate" data-rate="3">3
                 <span class="rate" data-rate="4">4
                     <span class="rate" data-rate="5">5
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
```

If you click on a higher number than 1, you will trigger multiple events.

The reason is clearly because of the nested elements. My question is, how can I make it so when user clicks on a number, it only triggers *that* event... **without changing the HTML**?

Comment: This... is actually quite an intriguing one. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of [event bubbling](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)
Use

```
$( document ).on( 'click touch', '.rate', function(e) {
   alert( $(this).data('rate') );
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Those bubbles have given me a 30 minute headache. Thanks! Will accept shortly.